# To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I'm running into this error and I can't quite figure it out.  I'm posting data to my controller via PostMan in Chrome, reaching the CreateUserAndAccount method, and receiving this error:

```
To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".
```

Here is my controller:

```
[System.Web.Http.Authorize]
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
        // POST: /api/register
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        [System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        //public HttpResponseMessage Register(RegisterModel model, string returnUrl)
        public HttpResponseMessage Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password); // blows up here
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

I'm using the same "InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute" class as the MVC SPA template:

```
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
        private static object _initializerLock = new object();
        private static bool _isInitialized;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
            LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
        }

        private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
        {
            public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

                try
                {
                    using (var context = new UsersContext())
                    {
                        if (!context.Database.Exists())
                        {
                            // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                        }
                    }

                    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in my web.config I have enabled simpleMembership:

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
```

What else could it be?

Edit: I just tried the tip found in this link:

http://insomniacgeek.com/to-call-this-method-the-membership-provider-property-must-be-an-instance-of-extendedmembershipprovider/

And I'm now getting

> You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method
>   before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call
>   should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.

Any suggestions would be awesome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem.  I was referencing System.Web.MVC in my InitializeAttribute class... it should have been System.Web.Http.

Comment: Can you explain? When I change my reference to Http, it won't compile any more. What, exactly, is being referenced in both Http and MVC?

Comment: @vbullinger Check your references (right click > add reference) and make sure system.web.http is included in your project.  also look at the msdn docs if you need to know more about the innards

Comment: Really bad explanation.