# MVC4, PostgreSQL, pgProvider, error: "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, membership-provider, npgsql

I'm using MVC4, postgres 9.2, Npgsql and pgProvider as membership provider. When I login using OAuth, it throws the next error:

```
To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".

Source Error:

Line 144:            if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
Line 145:            {


Source File: c:\VS\Web\Controllers\AccountController.cs    Line: 144
```

and my Web.config configuration:

```
<membership defaultProvider="pgMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="pgMembershipProvider" type="pgProvider.pgMembershipProvider, pgProvider" applicationName="pgProvider.Tests"/>
  </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager defaultProvider="pgRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="pgRoleProvider" type="pgProvider.pgRoleProvider, pgProvider" applicationName="pgProvider.Tests"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

And I set copy local true to WebMatrix as others threads[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052193/error-membership-provider-property-must-be-an-instance-of-extendedmembershipp) suggest but doesn't work.

Perhaps pgProvider doesn't support ExtendedMembershipProvider, but I don't see any alternative to use OAuth and Postgres. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this link of [Jon Galloway](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway//simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates), it is not possible work SimpleMembership with old providers of Membership.